# Вывод в word из datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-word, export

Есть такая проблема с экспортом, я прикрепляю шаблон внизу, и там есть datagridview, и как мне сделать вывод в word, когда я выбираю интервал дат (1 неделя), и он выводится в шаблон, но я не могу понять, как сделать, что бы было введено в определенной колонке дня недели. Я буду очень благодарен всем, кто поможет, в противном случае осталось только это и 1 день
[image: Шаблон]

[image: Данные]

Код на вывод в word:

```
 met();
            Word.Application wApp = new Word.Application();
            wApp.Visible = true;
            object missing = Type.Missing;
            object falseValue = false;
            Word.Document wordDocument = wApp.Documents.Open(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"C:\Users\Даниил\Downloads\raspisanie-na-10-urokov.doc"));
            ReplaceWordStub("{ot}", ordersgrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), wordDocument);
            ReplaceWordStub("{do}", ordersgrid.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), wordDocument);
            Word.Table tb = wordDocument.Tables[1];
            foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in guna2DataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                Word.Row r = tb.Rows.Add();
                for (var i = 1; i <= guna2DataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
                    r.Cells[i].Range.Text = rw.Cells[i - 1].Value.ToString().Trim();
            }
            tb.Rows[2].Delete(); // удаляем пустую строку после шапки таблицы
```

Вот что получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пришлось переделать шаблон просто других вариантов нету

Comment: у вас в word шаблоне есть 2 тега {от} и {до}. Сделайте такие-же теги в стрчке дня недели и заполняйте свою таблицу. По другому раскидать я думаю не получиться. Либо как вариант читать Word документ отфильтровать данные и затем по сравнению входных и исходящих данных заполнять таблицу. Но первый вариант проще будет

Comment: смотрите от и до это дата в datetimepicker неделю к примеру и выводятся только те которые попали а потом как то заносилось

Comment: Я понимаю о чем вы. Предлагаю вам сделать тоже самое с днями недели

Comment: Я вот добавил код который у меня просто вывод производит

Comment: но только как мне его изменить

Comment: Смотрите, у библиотеки есть интерфейс `Find`  с помощью которого вы реализуете поиск по тегам и далее перезаписываете нужными данными  
`World.Find.Replacement.Text = value`. Где value ваши данные заменяете нужным текстом `Word.Find find = wApp.Selection.Find;
                    find.Text = item.Key; //тут теги которые вы сделаете
                    find.Replacement.Text = item.Value;` // тут всё остальное

Comment: а как мне тогда вывести в столбец а не в строку

Comment: первое что приходит в голову, отсортировать по дням. Потом приступить к поиску тега, затем с помощью массива и цикла произвести заполнение.

Comment: а есть какие нибудь легче способы или вообще шаблон переделать

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста завтра сдавать программу

Comment: Вы что-то сделали ? Покажите результат, в каком месте у Вас не получается

Comment: я вот добавил что сделал

Comment: Всё получилось в конечном итоге ?

Comment: не совсем как хотелось но реализовал